# Colors are washed out and blacks are gray on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, colors, kde5

I've recently installed Kubuntu 20.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 but one thing that has bugged me, and still does, both live booting and installed is that my display colors are **washed out**.

I've tried every single fix on this forum for this issue that I could find (maybe 5-8 of them?) and none of them seemed to work.

I've also looked outside this forum and all in all the most recommended "*fix*" was `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"` but it simply doesn't work.

`OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64`
`Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic`
`CPU: Intel Pentium G4400 (2) @ 3.300GHz`
`GPU: Intel HD Graphics 510`

***Edit:***

So I was in a Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon live boot a little bit ago and there too my colors didn't display correctly. Unrelated to that, I was messing around with the display resolution and when i set it to 1600x900 all the colors displayed correctly and blacks were black instead of gray.

So I went back to my Kubuntu, set the resolution to 1600x900 and lo and behold.

The colors display correctly.

Another thing to keep in mind is that when i went into Steam Big Picture Mode, Steam warned me when I changed the resolution to 1920x1080 that I only have an  amount of video memory and it could have significant performance issues. Although it didn't have any performance issues whatsoever and performed better than I have ever seen Steam Big Picture Mode perform (since I'm used to Windows), the warning's still something to keep in mind, I guess.

*End of edit*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure your display supports full RGB?  If you broadcast full spectrum and your display uses limited RGB, colors will look washed out.  You should set RGB to match your display.

Comment: Colors look perfectly fine in Windows 10 on the same monitor settings. And the monitor is set to RGB.

Comment: @Nmath Hi, please take a look at my edit if you have the time. :)

Comment: Hi, @Nmath. I haven't solved my problem. The colors are proper only at 1600x900 resolution. Switching to 1920x1080 brings back the washed out colors. For that reason, this problem **isn't** solved.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how the Consumer Electronics Association specified digital TV connections. If your monitor can be connected to A/V equipment it will advertise some standard TV resolutions (such as 1920x1080@60Hz) which will be fed "limited range" 16:235 pixel values that cause washed out colors when your monitor is expecting 0:255.
Since Linux is also run on media players and receivers I can understand why Intel is hesitant to make it work like on Windows. Unfortunately there does not seem to be any boot time override and we are stuck with running
`xrandr --output <connector> --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"`
during X startup, where  is the one your monitor is on. (Use `xrandr --listmonitors`)

That said, if your computer and monitor support DisplayPort, that connection should default to full range.

Another option is to add a non standard resolution to your Xorg configuration and set that in your desktop environment. I.e. 1080p at 63 Hz would not be recognized as a TV standard and default to full range.

Last not least you can try creating your own EDID file (which advertises a monitors capabilities) based on the one your monitor provides and make Linux use that instead. I haven't tried that myself, but it should give you correct colors during boot. The downside to that is that you cannot provide different EDIDs for different monitors in this fashion. (Search for drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware and tools like wxEDID)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the instructions from [Quick Tip: Setting the Color Space Value in Wayland](https://www.brad-x.com/2017/08/07/quick-tip-setting-the-color-space-value-in-wayland/) by Brad T. Laue, I came up with the following solution (sort of):

1. Install `libdrm-tests` and run `proptest`.
2. For the monitor that has this issue, identify connector number and also the number of the "Broadcast RGB" property.
3. Switch to TTY console and run:

```
/usr/bin/proptest -M i915 -D /dev/dri/card0 <ID_of_connector> connector <ID_of_property> <value>
```

Try `<value>` of 1 or 2. The result is instant. Your screen should go black for a second, then the black background of the console should be darker than before.

4. Make this permanent by editing GDM3 service configuration to run this command before GDM3 starts. Make a backup:

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service /lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service.bak
```

Then edit the file with **nano**:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service
```

5. In the `[Service]` section, add before any other entries:

```
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/proptest -M i915 -D /dev/dri/card0 74 connector 76 1
```

This is the command for my system. Do **not** forget the `-` before the command. This instructs **systemd** to continue in case the command fails (non-zero return code).

6. Save and reboot.

I tested this on Ubuntu 21.04 Wayland running on Intel UHD Graphics 630.

I made a detailed post about this "washed out colors" issue on my blog: [Set full RGB to HDMI monitor on Ubuntu](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2021/08/hdmi-picture-quantization-range-linux.html). The problem I have now is that this fix stopped working out of a sudden, without me changing anything. The command fails on boot with status `243/CREDENTIALS`, but it works after I am logged in and issue a restart of GDM3 from terminal.

Comment: i've just accepted it does this on VGA but not on DVI, also it wasn't on Wayland so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯